# Can't add custom.tpl to my module

Tags: routes, theming

I create a custom module that included hook_menu and hook_block_info and ...
i wanna add a tpl to this module . here is my code :

```
        function hookmenu_menu() {
            $items['hookmenu'] = array(
                'title' => 'Soheil',
                'page callback' => 'hook',
                'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
                'page callback' => 'myhook_page',
                'access arguments' =>array('administer content'),
            );
            return $items;
        }

        /*
         * page callback
         */
        function myhook_page(){

            return theme('my_custom_template');
        }

    /*
 * Implement hook_theme().
 */
function custom_example_theme(){
    return array(
        'my_custom_template' => array(

            'template' => 'custom-page',
        ),
    );
}
```

and i created a `custom-page.tpl` and wrote hello world .
result : i can see my page but i can't see hello world

thx

Answer (score 2):

Your file needs to be named

custom-page.tpl.php

Note the .php extension. You might need to clear the caches to make that change show up

You also need either a `variables` or `render element` property as outlined in [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)

Comment: thx for your answer , i just add these :  function custom_example_theme(){
    return array(
        'my_custom_template' => array(
            'variables' => array(
                'user' => NULL,
                'node' => NULL,
            ),
            // file name will be custom-page.tpl.php
            'template' => 'custom-page',
        ),
    );
}  
and clear the cash but nothing changed

Comment: Hmm it should do, is the custom-page.tpl.php file in the root of the module?

Comment: function custom_example_theme(){ 
    return array( 
        'my_custom_template' => array( 'variables' => array( 'user' => NULL, 'node' => NULL, ),
        'template' => 'custom-page')
    ); 
}

Comment: @Clive yes i put it there

Comment: @clive sorry for this question :is it important to put this this code bottom of codes or bottom of callback function ?